# How to load the data without clicking on the link?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a MVC app.
I am trying to develop a comment box.

I have already written a code , in this code , I have written the process like, 
When user click on **Show Comment** link comments get appeared.

Now, I want to change the functionality, Without clicking on show Comments button , All comments should be load.

I am trying to do this but its not working.

Show Comments Link Code

```
 <div class="span12" style="margin-left:0px; margin-top:50px;">
      <span style="font-size:16px;">
          @Ajax.ActionLink("Show Comments", null, null, null, new { id = Model.Id, @class = "addremark" })

        <div class="RemarkBox"></div>
        <span class="CommentAdd"></span>
      </div>
```

I want to load the comments when page is load, I am expecting commments show load while loading the page, but still I want to click on the **Show Comment** link.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('a.addremark').click(addremarkClick);

    // Call on load also
    addremarkClick();

    });

    function addremarkClick(event)
    {

        var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ShowCommentBox", "Comment", new { Id = "idValue", EntityType = "Payment" }))';
        if (typeof event !== 'undefined') url = url.replace("idValue", event.target.id);
        else url = url.replace("idValue", $('a.addremark')[0].id);
        $('.RemarkBox').load(url);
        $(this).closest('div').find('div.RemarkBox').show();
        return false;
    }

function addremarkClick()
    {
        alert("Clciked");
        var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ShowCommentBox", "Comment", new { Id = "idValue", EntityType = "Payment" }))';
         if (typeof event !== 'undefined') url = url.replace("idValue", event.target.id);
         else url = url.replace("idValue", $('a.addremark')[0].id);
         $('.RemarkBox').load(url);
         $(this).closest('div').find('div.RemarkBox').show();
         return false;
    }
```

Comment: the browser js console is showing some errors? the code should work unless the comment block is not loaded and the click event could not be fired.

Comment: I am more interested in addremarkClick() event , It fires  alert window is also appear but comment doesn't appear.

Comment: I can suggest to live debug the code and check the selector "$(this).closest('div') if is null or is selecting the correct div

Answer (score 1):

The best approach will be to load the page first and then using js, get the list of show comment links available `$('a.addremark')` and then instead of triggering a click event, you can iterate over the collection and then make AJAX calls so that the comments are loaded during the runtime without user clicking on the link.

Also, it will be useful to have `SetTimeOut` javascript call that refreshes the comments on the page after a particular duration, so the users do not also have to refresh the page or click on links to view updated comments. You can see a similar approach used in Stackoverflow which suddenly asked me to click to reload a post to view the edits. so it will give better usability.

**EDIT**

The following can be the steps

> 1. Page Load completes, after the document is ready, call a javascript method that finds all the links with the class as `addremark`.
> 2. For each link element, you will associate with it the post id for which the comment is to be fetched for
> 3. Make AJAX call with the postid and then get all the comments and then update it in the corresponding div's.
> 4. The above method can be passed a parameter to the setInterval of javascript method. For this method please refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: @user1650894: I have explained the steps in the above post.

Answer (score 0):

insert following js in your page, do not insert it in common js.

```
<script>
       window.setInterval(function(){
          addremarkClick();
          }, 600000);// run this after every minute
</script>
```

Comment: add same as above jquery ajax post to get comment and add in any html, or you can specify another window.load() event to do some other task.